# Redis : Get all keys by providing one of the value in the values list

Tags: caching, redis, google-cloud-memorystore, in-memory-cache

In redis I'm planning to store key as a unique string and value will be a list.

I have a use case where I need to do 2 things.

First, I need to get all the values associated with a key by providing the key as input.
Second, I want to get all the keys associated with a value by providing one of the value in the values list.

Second part is where I need the advice, how we can achive this ?
I cannot get all the keys or key value pair and loop through because I will have millions of entries in Redis.

Comment: There does not seem to be a way to get all the keys associated with a value by providing one of the values in the values list in the memorystore ,this will probably make loops through a large entries .However what seems to be possible is to understand that we can do is to use any language like a function [getAllKeys()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.getallkeys.php) for the php library

Answer (score 1):

As  mentioned in the comment above the retrieving of all keys with associated value at will probably sometimes create a performance issue as this will be a run through large entries.As also suggested in the [official documentation about retrieving data from the memory caches](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/using-memorystore?tab=go#using_redis_commands_to_store_and_retrieve_data_in_the_cache) you can try and use the following Redis command to get the value and see if that is what can solve your purpose.

- [GET](https://redis.io/commands/get)
- [MGET](https://redis.io/commands/mget)